# SQL Query, list all x where x has >1 z

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my model

[image]

assume everything's been implemented correctly, what i need to do is query modules which have classes on more than one campus. In other words "Find the list of modules which have classes on more than one campus"

```
SELECT module_id FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT module_id, room FROM timetable
        )a JOIN (SELECT building, room FROM rooms)b USING (room)
    )c JOIN (SELECT campus, building FROM buildings)d USING (building) 
)e GROUP BY module_id,campus HAVING COUNT(campus) > 1;
```

this is what i've got but it's not doing what i want it to

Answer (score 0):

You have **way** too many nested queries!

You just need a simple query that joins all your tables correctly, then put the group on it, then put having on it. There is no reason to use a nested query here, the query will look like

```
select [columns you want to return]
from timetable
join module on [...]
join room on [...]
join building on [...]
group by [columns you want to return]
having count(*) > 1;
```

Good luck with the rest of your homework!